# Property templates (multiple properties in multiple classes with same\similar code)?

Tags: c#, .net

In a c# project (and MVC project to be exact) I have some partial classes. Some of those classes have `DateTime` properties and I need to expand their functionality a bit. The thing I'm doing is adding a helper property to the class that let's me alter the time separately.

So if I have a `SomeDate` property in the generated partial class I would add this to the not generated part of the class:

```
DateTime? _someDateTime;
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime? SomeDateTime
{
    get
    {
        if (_someDateTime == null)
        {
            if (SomeDate.HasValue)
            {
                _someDateTime = SomeDate;
            }
        }
        return _someDateTime;
    }
    set
    {
        _someDateTime = value;
    }
}
```

With some extra code elsewhere I can easily enough manipulate the time of `SomeDate` property in the way that I want.

Now I would need to have similar helper properties related to other properties in this and other partial classes. Is there some alternative to copy-pasting the code above?

P.S. After writing this question, some ideas started forming in my mind. They involve inheriting from `DateTime` and writing a new attribute that does nothing but provide name of the related `DateTime` property.

Comment: If you have a partial class, the property is already "shared", it is the same class. Do you want to have the property (and its altering logic) in a different class?

Comment: @derape I need to share the logic of `SomeDateTime` with other classes and even properties. For example, in one class I might have `DateTime` properties like `Start` and `End` and need such helper property for each one. Does this make my problem more clear?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to do that:

- As you already stated: create a wrapper class which provides the functionality you need which manipulates the state of the object
- Similar to the first one, create an extension method which then manipulates a DateTime instance
- Create a "Helper" class, which is able to change a DateTime instance

It really depends on the context of your code as well on the requirements, constraints, etc.

Comment: The base idea is that I need a separate property for the time part of a `DateTime` property. Manipulating the time isn't a goal in itself, but using a separate property to do so is.

Comment: So basically you want the "original" DateTime property represented in a "different" format/state?